# How to control paste behaviour in data.frame for integer type columns?

Tags: r

Here is the sample code, which produces interesting output:

```
> gg<-data.frame(x=c("a","b"),y=as.integer(c(1000,100000)))
> gg
  x      y
1 a   1000
2 b 100000
> apply(gg,1,paste,collapse="")
[1] "a  1000" "b100000"
> apply(gg[1,],1,paste,collapse="")
      1 
"a1000"
```

In the first `apply` run, R somehow knows how to pad additional spaces. How does it do that and is it possible to control this behaviour?

Comment: Looks like it's assuming that both should character atomics of the same length. Ergo setting sep=[value] to that dynamically? What is the desired output you want?

Comment: From `?apply`, "apply attempts to coerce [X] to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array". `as.matrix()` converts to character by `format()`, and this has an argument `trim`, which you could try to change to TRUE to suppress leading blanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apply` only works on an array or matrix, so it first has to convert your data.frame to a matrix.  `as.matrix(gg)` creates the padding.

Looking at `as.matrix.data.frame`, the padding is caused by a call to `format` (`format.default`, actually), which eventually calls `prettyNum`.  `prettyNum` has a `preserve.width` argument with a default of `"common"`.

If you want more control over this behavior, convert each column in your data.frame to a character vector before calling `apply`:

```
gg[,2] <- as.character(gg[,2])
apply(gg,1,paste,collapse="")
# [1] "a1000"   "b100000"
```